# Unable to Delete Partition in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

I have a poorly formatted partition in Athena. I partition on year, month, day, and hour as integer columns, but mistakenly created partitions as floats.

i.e

`/year=2019.0/month=4.0/day=22.0/hour=6.0`

instead of

`/year=2019/month=4/day=22/hour=6`

I removed the s3 files responsible and ran a `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` but the partition wasn't removed. I tried removing the partition manually with-

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PARTITION (year=2019.0)
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PARTITION (year='2019.0')
```

But I got the error

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10006]: Partition not found (year = null)

Notice `year = null`. It seems Athena doesn't know what to do with decimals.

How do I get rid of this faulty partition?

EDIT:

The only way I was able to resolve this was to recreate the table and repair it. Still looking for another solution because that would be a bummer in prod.

Answer (score 3):

Could you once try with these methods to drop all partitions:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PARTITION (year > 0.0);
(or)
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PARTITION (year > 0);
```

**`(or)`**

Change the `datatype` of **`year`** to **`String`**
then try to drop the partitions

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PARTITION (year='2019.0')
```

Comment: I added partitions with the wrong date format, which then could not be deleted because they were not valid dates.  Changing the type in the schema in Glue to "string" allowed me to delete partitions.  After that, I was able to change back to date.  Hope the extra about glue helps and thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue, but my partition key was in timestamp format and I accidentally created a partition with a string value. In my case worked `ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PARTITION (partition_key = "")` (wrong value was non-empty string) and then `MSCK REPAIR TABLE my_table`. It seems that Athena somehow interpreted empty string and deleted corrupted partitions.